# Can someone explain exactly how Booksleeve and Redis work together and it's application in a SignalR app?

Tags: redis, signalr, azureservicebus, booksleeve

We are implementing scale-out for our SignalR app and trying to avoid a single point of failure in our cluster.  Thus, more than one Redis message bus server is required.

The problem with implementing Redis Sentinel is that upon fail-over, a the client needs to connect to a new endpoint [address], which would require the SignalR application to be restarted (Redis endpoint defined in Application_Start()).

Not an option.

I'm trying to understand if/how Booksleeve will help, and would like some explain this.

The issue is that we can only have one single endpoint defined for message bus.  A hardware solution is not currently an option.

Would the SignalR application connect to a Booksleeve wrapper, which maintains the list of master/slaves?

Another option using Azure Service Bus.  However, the [instructions](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/performance-and-scaling/scaleout-with-windows-azure-service-bus) for *Wiring Up the Windows Azure Service Bus Provider* indicate there are still problems with this:

> Note, this web site is an ASP.NET site that runs in an Azure web role.
>   As of 1.0alpha2 there are some bugs in AzureWebSites due to which
>   ServiceBus Scale out scenarios do not work well. We are working on
>   resolving this for the future

Comment: Can you DNS your Redis endpoint? So then you only need to change your pointer record after failover (not restart app pool).

Comment: Did you try reading the code? https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Redis/RedisMessageBus.cs. It's a single file, so not that hard to grok.

Comment: Isn't that bug warning specific to Azure Web Sites (and not Cloud Services)? That's how I read it.

Comment: I've now checked the SignalR code, and it is not using `ConnectionUtils`... so *at the moment* SignalR would only connect to a single node. Note that until redis-cluster arrives, multiple redis nodes is not strictly about "scale out scenarios", since any group can have only one master. You can, of course, use the slaves for querying (read-only) and pub/sub listening.

Comment: @dfowler it does raise some interesting points, though; there are alternative connection creation options that offer more flexibility here (see answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know the specifics of how SignalR does the connect, but: BookSleeve already offers some concessions towards failover nodes. In particular, the `ConnectionUtils.Connect` method takes a string (ideal for web.config configuration values etc), which can include **multiple** redis nodes, and BookSleeve will then try to locate the most appropriate node to connect to. If the nodes mentioned in the string are regular redis nodes, it will attempt to connect to a master, otherwise falling back to a slave (optionally promoting the slave in the process). If the nodes mentioned are sentinel nodes, it will ask sentinel to nominate a serer to connect to.

What BookSleeve *doesn't* offer at the moment is a redundant connection wrapper that will automatically reconnect. That is on the road-map, but isn't difficult to do in the calling code. I plan to add more support for this at the same time as implementing redis-cluster support.

But: all that is from a BookSleeve perspective - I can't comment on SignalR specifically.

Comment: That's brand new logic that was recently added to Booksleeve and there is a bug filed to support it in SignalR. We'll make it a bit more flexible in the future so you can pass in a connection factory or something similar.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what's needed.  Booksleeve will issue the IP address/port for the next active server at failover.  The problem is that SignalR can only accept one endpoint.  If a change occurs, the application has to be restarted.  For now, the only way around this, that I can see, is to use a static IP address (load balancer) and the LB performs the failover.  Other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

BookSleeve 1.3.41.0 supports Redis sentinel. Deployment configuration we use: 1 master redis, 1 slave redis. Each box has sentinel (one for master, one for slave). Clients connect to sentinel first, sentinel then redirects them to active master.

This is how it is implemented in client code:

```
public class OwinStartup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var config = new WebClientRedisScaleoutConfiguration();
        GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseRedis(config);
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}

public class WebClientRedisScaleoutConfiguration : RedisScaleoutConfiguration
{
    public WebClientRedisScaleoutConfiguration()
        : base(() => getRedisConnection(), WebUIConfiguration.Default.Redis.EventKey)
    { }

    private static BookSleeve.RedisConnection _recentConnection;
    private static BookSleeve.RedisConnection getRedisConnection()
    {
        var log = new TraceTextWriter();
        var connection = BookSleeve.ConnectionUtils.Connect("sentinel1:23679,sentinel2:23679,serviceName=WebClient", log);
        if (connection != null)
        {
            _recentConnection = connection;
            return connection;
        }

        if (_recentConnection != null)
        {
            return _recentConnection;
        }

        // Cannot return null nor throw exception -- this will break reconnection cycle.
        return new BookSleeve.RedisConnection(string.Empty);
    }
}
```

Hot to configure redis.
**Common steps**
Download Redis for windows http://redis.io/download
Unzip to c:\redis

**Master (only very first redis box, only one such config)**

1. Create Redis service: execute command within redis directory `redis-server --service-install redis.conf --service-name redis`
2. Start Redis service
3. Ensure Redis is listing port 6379

**Slave (other boxes)**

1. Update redis.conf: add line `slaveof masterAddr 6379` where `masterAddr`
   is address where redis in master mode is running, 6379 is default
   redis port.
2. Create Redis service: execute command within redis directory `redis-server --service-install redis.conf --service-name redis`
3. Start Redis service
4. Ensure Redis is listing port 6379

**Sentinel (common for master and slave)**

1. Create file redis-sentinel.conf with content:
   `port 26379 
   logfile "redis-sentinel1.log" 
   sentinel monitor WebClient masterAddr 6379 1`

   where masterAddr is address where redis in master mode is running,
   6379 is default redis port, 1 is quorum (number of host that makes
   decision is server down or not). `WebClient` is group name. You specify it in client code `ConnectionUtils.Connect("...,serviceName=WebClient...")`
2. Create redis sentinel service:execute command within redis directory `redis-server --service-install redis-sentinel.conf --service-name redis-sentinel --sentinel`
3. Start redis-sentinel service